# Indexing mode value cannot be 'none' when automatic indexing is specified as 'true'

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When removing indexing, I get the following error when trying to insert a document:

```
{{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Indexing mode value cannot be 'none' when automatic indexing is specified as 'true'.\"]}..."
}}
```

I am using the SDK to do this:

```
collection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.None;

client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(collection).Wait();
```

I cannot find anything online with regards to this error or for specifying automatic indexing to true/false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is missing in the docs.

Automatic Indexing needs to be set to `false` for `IndexingMode.None`.

```c#
collection.IndexingPolicy.Automatic = false;

collection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.None;

client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(collection).Wait();
```

Comment: Ah thanks. So, would this be the means of providing your own indexing entirely? Provided that the policy is set to lazy or consistent, of course. As I understand, the default, automatic index essentially creates a hash and range index on every resource (and subresource) attribute, which is complete overkill in many cases.

Comment: These settings will turn indexing completely off. If you are looking to apply custom index policies, you will want to define custom paths. By default, a wildcard path, `/*`, is included in the indexing policy, which can be interpretative as indexing every property under the root document. To switch over completely to a custom index policy, exclude the root wildcard path ,`/*`, and include only your custom paths (e.g. `/prop/subprop/?`)

Comment: You can find a reference here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/

Comment: I cannot seem to exclude all with the `/*` path.  I get the following error: _The indexing path '\\/*' could not be accepted. Please ensure that the path is unique across all sets of indexing paths and it's valid._ I'm using lazy mode and the indexes are set as default.

Comment: I created a question for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981829/documentdb-removing-default-indexing).

Comment: One more intuitiveness of microsoft is that if the indexing is None then TTL cannot be set. I just cannot figure out what is the relation between this. Microsoft creates complex matrixes of what works with what and not.