# Azure RUs on cosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to find out how RUs are working in order to optimize the requests made to the DB.

I have a simple query where is select by id

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id='cl0'
```

That query costs `277.08` RUs

Then I have another query where I select by another property

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name[0].id='35bfea78-ccda-4cc5-9539-bd7ff1dd474b'
```

That query costs `2.95` RUs

I cant figure out why there is that a big a difference in the consumed RUs between these two queries.

Thw two queries return the exact same result

```
[
    {
        "label": "class",
        "id": "cl0",
        "_id": "cl0",
        "name": [
            {
                "_value": "C0.Iklos0",
                "id": "35bfea78-ccda-4cc5-9539-bd7ff1dd474b"
            }
        ],
        "_rid": "6Ds6AJHyfgBfAAAAADFT==",
        "_self": "dbs/6Ds4FA==/colls/6Ds6DFewfgA=/docs/6Ds6AJHyfgBdESFAAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"00007200-0000-0000-0000-w3we73140000\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1528722196
    }
]
```

Comment: Do all documents within your collection have exactly the same schema? Is it possible that there are lots of documents within your collection that have an id property, but many fewer that have a name[0].id property?

Comment: Hi,any progress now? If you think my answer is helpful for you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue previously so you are not the only person facing this issue. I provide you with two solutions.

1.sql `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id='cl0'` query documents across total database.If you could make a partition key to properly field, it will greatly improve your performance.
You could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#best-practices-when-choosing-a-partition-key) to know how to choose partition key.

2.I founded below answer in the thread: [Azure DocumentDB Query by Id is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684890/azure-documentdb-query-by-id-is-very-slow)

Microsoft support responded and they've resolved the issue. They've added IndexVersion 2 for the collection. Unfortunately, it is not yet available from the portal and newly created accounts/collection are still not using the new version. You'll have to contact Microsoft Support to made changes to your accounts.

I suggest you committing feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to trace this announcement.

Hope it helps you.

-- Edit

To upgrade to index version 2 use the following code

```
var  collection = (await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(string.Format("/dbs/{0}/colls/{1}", databaseId, collectionId))).Resource;                
collection.SetPropertyValue("IndexVersion", 2);
var replacedCollection = await client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(collection);
```

Comment: Ok thanks for you answer and possible solutions. I will try that.

Comment: I have added code to show how to upgrade to index v2, its in the peer review Q, I don't think it warrants me adding a new answer

Answer (score 0):

RU consumption depends on your document size and your query, I will highly recommend below link to query metrics. If you want to tune your query or want to understand latency check query Feed Details

> x-ms-documentdb-query-metrics: 
>   totalExecutionTimeInMs=33.67;queryCompileTimeInMs=0.06;queryLogicalPlanBuildTimeInMs=0.02;queryPhysicalPlanBuildTimeInMs=0.10;queryOptimizationTimeInMs=0.00;VMExecutionTimeInMs=32.56;indexLookupTimeInMs=0.36;documentLoadTimeInMs=9.58;systemFunctionExecuteTimeInMs=0.00;userFunctionExecuteTimeInMs=0.00;retrievedDocumentCount=2000;retrievedDocumentSize=1125600;outputDocumentCount=2000;writeOutputTimeInMs=18.10;indexUtilizationRatio=1.00
>   x-ms-request-charge: 604.42

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics