# Cosmos Db collection with certain indexes included, only

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to `exclude` all and `include` only certain indexes on a collection in CosmosDb.

Here is my code:

```
// A property in the class...
public override IEnumerable<IncludedPath> CollectionIndexes => new List<IncludedPath>
{
     new IncludedPath{ Path= "/\"CreatedOnUtc\""  }, // I have tried "/CreatedOnUtc" as well
     // few more indexes...    
};

// Code in the CreateCollection method...
collection.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.Add(new ExcludedPath { Path = "/*" }); // I have tried the code without this line as well
foreach (var path in CollectionIndexes) // Add indexes over certain properties only.
{
     collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(path);
}
```

When I run the code, I get this very exception ever single time:

> Message: {"Errors":["The indexing path '/\"CreatedOnUtc\"' could not be
>   accepted, failed near position '5'. Please ensure that the path is a
>   valid path. Common errors include invalid characters or absence of
>   quotes around labels."]} ActivityId:
>   2627fe24-64a0-46b3-bf9a-13cb160c17a7, Request URI:
>   /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/,
>   RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.22.0.0,
>   documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/64-bit
>   MicrosoftWindowsNT/10.0.16299.0

When I change the path to `"/CreatedOnUtc"`, I still get to see the same message:

> Message: {"Errors":["The indexing path '/CreatedOnUtc' could not be accepted,
>   failed near position '3'. Please ensure that the path is a valid path.
>   Common errors include invalid characters or absence of quotes around
>   labels."]} ActivityId: 30dc7429-df87-4080-912e-60aa731ae809, Request
>   URI:
>   /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/,
>   RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.22.0.0,
>   documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/64-bit
>   MicrosoftWindowsNT/10.0.16299.0

What am I missing out on? It seems to be something very basic but I have wasted 24 hours on this trying out various combinations!

I am using the C# Sql API to do so. I am trying this out on the `CosmosDb Emulator` on my local PC.

Comment: Why did you do `"/\"id\""` and not simply `"/id"`?

Comment: I have tried `"/id"` as well..

Comment: I don't see you specifying the index type in the example. I am talking about something like this: `Indexes = new Collection<Index> { new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = 20 } } });`

Comment: I think I have tried that as well, I will try again and get back here

Comment: Oh wait a second. Did you try removing the `id`? As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989880/7523974) "the `id` is implicitly treated as the document's primary key - in which, id will always be indexed with uniqueness enforced."

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well!, I will just update the question again... Give me few minutes

Comment: I see you have absolute paths. Have you tried adding the special characters needed at the end? For example the path for `CreatedOnUtc` should be `/CreatedOnUtc/?`

Comment: It worked! Why did the question mark help?

Comment: Because it is a necessary wildcard character. It’s actually in the documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174376/discussion-between-bit-and-nick-chapsas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the a necessary wildcard character `?` at the end of the index path.

The `?` character at the end of the index path is required to serve queries that query on this property. The character `*` should be used if you are planing to query on sub properties of the property for this path.

You can read more about this on the [indexing policies documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies)

Comment: Thank you! I had been through numerous articles and videos; yet I wonder how did I miss the `?`